# Missing $ inserted while using Cases environment

Tags: cases

```
f(n) = \begin{cases} n/2 &\mbox{if } n \equiv 0 \\
(3n +1)/2 & \mbox{if } n \equiv 1 \end{cases}
```

I read somewhere that in the cases environment it doesn't require $ and when I do try and put $, it says I am still missing it. I am fairly new to Latex and quite confused.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\title{}
\author{} 
\date{} 

\begin{document} 
\maketitle
\begin{tabbing}

\underline{\textbf{Problem 13.}} \\

f(n) = \begin{cases} n/2 &\mbox{if } n \equiv 0 \\
(3n +1)/2 & \mbox{if } n \equiv 1 \end{cases}

\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to text.stackexchange.com. Since you seemingly are familiar with the basics of coding, you better present your problem in a full document layout with documentclass, etc. in order to reproduce the error you got so that the others can help you.

Comment: Okay, I posted my whole code, but it runs fine once I remove the cases environment

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. please read an introduction to LaTeX before moving any further.

Comment: The line with `\begin{cases}` is almost at the end of the file.  The `cases` environment itself must be in math mode, and it isn't.  Add `$` at each end, as `$\begin{cases} ... \end{cases}$`.

Comment: Oh, Thank you it works now

Comment: Actually, the initial `$` should go before `f(n)`.  That whole expression is math.

Comment: You probably want `\[ f(n) = \begin{cases}... \end{cases} \]` so that the equation is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

In relation by comments of the very good users I add a MWE. I have delete `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` and I have added the package `\usepackage{parskip}` with the same function, `\text{if }` instead of `\mbox{if }`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\title{}
\author{} 
\date{\today} 

\begin{document} 
\maketitle
\begin{tabbing}
\underline{\textbf{Problem 13.}} \\
$f(n) = \begin{cases} n/2 &\text{if } n \equiv 0 \\
(3n +1)/2 & \text{if } n \equiv 1 \end{cases}$
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

[image]